# Javascript Array Length Confusion Issue

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am having trouble understanding an answer to a question.

I was told to find the last element in any array the answer would be for example   :

```
alert(countries[countries.length - 1]);
```

However, I was told to go loop through the entire list of array I would put for example

```
for(counter=0; counter < presidents.length; counter++) { 
    document.write(presidents[counter]);
}
```

Question is....
Why is is    `counter < presidents.length` and not     `counter < presidents.length-1` like in the example before?

Comment: Because `<` isn't `<=`, the condition will only be true up to when `counter` is `presidents.length-1`. *(`a < a` returns `false`)*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you need to print the last value too.

For example, let the array be,

```
var presidents = ["one", "two", "three", "four"];
```

Here, `presidents.length = 4`.
Now, if you do `counter < presidents.length-1` then counter goes from **0 to 2**.

You either need to do
`counter <= presidents.length-1` or `counter < presidents.length`
 in order to make `counter` go from **0 till 3**.

PS: Array indices begin from 0 in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Because array index start with zero and last element will be in (size-1) position. In for loop, you are using less than(<) symbol. It will be < size or <= (size -1).

Answer (score 0):

Probably also worth mentioning that the for loop works because of when things happen.  Take the following statement:

```js
for ([initialExpression]; [condition]; [incrementExpression]) {
  [statement]
}
```

`initialExpression` is evaluated immediately and is typically used to create a variable to increment, as you did with `counter=0`.

`condition` is evaluated **before** executing the statement.  If the condition is truthy, the statement is executed; if not, the loop is terminated.

`incrementExpression` is evaluated **after** executing the statement.  So, incrementing `counter` here informs the next `condition` evaluation.

Putting it together, the `condition` evaluation looks like this:

```js
if 0 < presidents.length // true
if 1 < presidents.length // true
. . .
if 44 < presidents.length // true and will produce the final president element
if 45 < presidents.length // false and terminate the loop
```